# Database design - flat or multitable

Tags: database, django, database-design

I am wondering how should I design the database for my towns, counties, voivodeships.

I have 2 ideas on how it should be working.

Idea 1 - simple:

Each of these types should be stored as separate table.

```
class Town(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    voivodeship = models.ForeignKey("Voivodeship", null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.ForeignKey("County", null=True, blank=True)
    town_type = models.ForeignKey("TownType", null=True, blank=True)
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)


class County(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    voivodship = models.ForeignKey("Voivodeship", null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Voivodeship(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    date_updated = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Idea 2 - a more complex:

The idea is to create 1 table for all places and create internal relationships between them.

```
class Location(MPTTModel):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=False)
     slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
     shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True, blank=True)

     date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     source = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=SOURCE_CHOICES)

     # Geonames metadata
     geoname_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=False)
     alternatenames = models.TextField()
     feature_class = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)

     # Teryt metadata

     # first_order_division = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Województwo")
     # second_order_division = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Powiat")
     # third_order_division = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="miasto")
     # fourth_order_division = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)

     type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=LOCATION_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=False)
     subtype = models.ForeignKey("self")

     # Location metadata
     lng = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
     lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
     population = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
     country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Which one would be the best in the long term run in terms of reliability, speed, options to add and update records?

What should I be aware of?

Comment: Without more information regarding what you're trying to achieve, I would go with the second option.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what do you mean by "internal relationships"?

Comment: @SamD internal relationship - `subtype = models.ForeignKey("self")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the flat design that I've described above. It has many advantages over table separation, for example in url patterns - it's way easier to maintain them because you can fit all locations in 1 pattern and you don't have to do extra view queries.

It's very easy to build structures using django-mptt so you can prototype solutions way faster by using flat database design. It's really easy to generate structures and breadcrumbs this way.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are trying to do however I think it would be better to use multiple tables. Having everything in one table can make your business logic quite a bit more complicated. Here are some examples:

- If the type of the `Location` is `foo`, then it's `__str__` should return one thing, and for `bar` type should return something else. Essentially you can end up with a whole bunch of `if` statements in `Location` methods which I don't think is very clean.
- Making model forms for different location types becomes a headache.
- Code might become harder to maintain or db migrations can bite you later on.

Also having everything in one table will not add any performance benefits since it still has a foreign key to itself so table joins will still have to be performed.

Comment: It has a flat or multi-table schema?